# Typescript - using the "for of" iternation creates the error "TypeError: element is not a function"

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have a basic function that should iterate through the values of an array and filter based on whether the element values exist..

The array has multiple depths:

```
   public menuList(): any {
        return [
            // SCHEDULER
            {
                route: ["", "scheduler"],
                name: "scheduler",
                moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName("../components/scheduler/scheduler"),
                title: "scheduler",
                nav: true,
                settings: {
                    icon: "user",
                    roles: ["Employee", "Admin"],
                    pos: "left"
                }
            },

            // CLIENTS
            {
                route: "clients",
                name: "clients",
                moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName("../components/clients/clientList/clientList"),
                title: "Clients",
                nav: true,
                settings: {
                    icon: "user",
                    roles: ["Employee", "Admin"],
                    pos: "left",
                    nav: [
                        {
                            route: "clients/ClientsList",
                            name: "clientList",
                            moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName("../components/clients/clientList/clientList"),
                            href: "#clients/clientsList",
                            title: "Client List",
                            settings: {
                                icon: "list",
                                roles: ["Employee", "Admin"],
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            settings: {
                                roles: ["Employee", "Admin"],
                                divider: true,
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            route: "clients/create",
                            name: "newClient",
                            moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName("../components/clients/newClient/newClient"),
                            href: "#clients/Create",
                            title: "Create Client",
                            settings: {
                                icon: "user",
                                roles: ["Employee", "Admin"],
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

This array has just two elements made up of subelements and in the client's element's case three elements under the "nav".

I am trying to construct a function that will traverse every level and remove those that doent satisfy the condition.

I started with this:

```
public userMenu(userName: string, userRole: string): any {

    var requiredElements = ["route", "name", "moduleId", "title", "nav"];

    for (let element of this.menuList()) {
        var filteredArray = element.filter(function (itm) {
            return requiredElements.indexOf(itm.requiredElements) > -1;
        })

    }
}
```

However I am getting an error on "element" on the line `var filteredArray = element.filter(function (itm) {`.

Its saying in the console:

> menu2.ts:122 Uncaught TypeError: element.filter is not a function
>       at Menu.73.Menu.userMenu (menu2.ts:122)

Which is that line..

How do I use the "for of" on the "menuList() and then be able to filter on it? in this case its saying that element is not something I can iterate over - or filter etc....

**EDIT**
As suggested I changed this to:

```
        public userMenu(userName: string, userRole: string): any {

    var requiredElements = ["route", "name", "moduleId", "title", "nav"];

    this.menuList().forEach(function (item) {
        var filteredArray = item.filter(function (itm) {
            return requiredElements.indexOf(itm.requiredElements) > -1;
        })

        console.log("filteredArray: ", filteredArray)
    })
}
```

and still got the same error.

What is it that is causing filter to fail and how do I iterate over and filter on my array above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to apply the filter to individual objects inside the array. That's not how it works: you're supposed to filter the entire array, not its elements individually.

Secondly, `.indexOf()` works for arrays. You can't use it to check for object keys. `.hasOwnProperty()` is for that purpose. Below it's used combined with `.every()` to check that all required keys exist.

Finally a minor point: since you're using TypeScript, you should avoid `var` in favor of `const` and `let`.

```
public userMenu(userName: string, userRole: string): any {

    const requiredElements = ["route", "name", "moduleId", "title", "nav"];

    const filteredArray = this.menuList().filter(function (itm) {
        return requiredElements.every(function(key) {
            return itm.hasOwnProperty(key);
        });
    });
}
```